# 2D ARRAY Word search problem Exception thrown error

Tags: c, arrays

the below program should take an 8x8 grid as input then how many words it will find and then words it is going to found. Then if it found a word it should replace it with a hashtag ('#'). Input spesification includes newlines like this ("\n" represented as newline) :

AWESOMEA(newline)

DEKTTADR(newline)

DZLZQUOC(newline)

RPEYRMDL(newline)

EEAEAPRY(newline)

SFFNQBDA(newline)

SSFTMASN(newline)

AWESOGER(newline)

5(newline)

ADDRESS(newline)

STUDY(newline)

LEAF(newline)

ROMAN(newline)

AWESOME(newline)

Code gives an

```
Exception thrown at 0x7ABCEE21 (ucrtbased.dll) in wordgrid.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x52444441. At VS2019. Not sure why. Any help is appreciated.
```

All hep is appreciated Thanks a lot :) Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    bool isword();
    int i, j, wordcount, numofwords;
    char tempgrid[8][8];
    char grid[8][8];
    char* words[15];

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            scanf("%c", &grid[i][j]);
        }
        scanf("\n");
    }
    scanf("\n");

    scanf("%d", &numofwords);

    scanf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < numofwords;i++)
    {       
            scanf("%[^\n]%*c", words[i]);
            scanf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            tempgrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        }

    }

   for (wordcount = 0, i = 0; (wordcount < numofwords) && (i < 8); i++, wordcount++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8;j++)
        {
            if (isword(grid, words[wordcount], i, j))
                tempgrid[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = tempgrid[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

bool isword(char grid[8][8], char* word, int heightcurrent, int widthcurrent)
{
    int y[] = { -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
    int x[] = { -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1 };
    int k, map, dirx, diry;
    int wordlen;

    if (grid[heightcurrent][widthcurrent] != word[0])
    {
        return false;
    }

    wordlen = strlen(word);

    for (map = 0; map < 8; map++)
    {
        diry = heightcurrent + y[map];
        dirx = widthcurrent + x[map];

        for (k = 1; k < wordlen ;k++)
        {
            if (diry > 8 || diry < 0 || dirx > 8 || dirx < 0)//checking if out of bounds
                break;
            if (grid[diry][dirx] != word[k])
                break;
            diry += x[map];
            dirx += y[map];
        }
        if (k + 1 == wordlen)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You allocate a *pointer* and then give a *pointer to the pointer* to `scanf`. Both are wrong and probably the cause. Just use the array directly.

Comment: Using the array directly does not give any output. :/

Comment: 'char* temp;' Defining another string then  'scanf("%[^\n]%*c", temp);' taking input to a temp  'strcpy(words[i],temp);' and then copying it in to array still gives errors :/ @SamiKuhmonen Can you helğ öe with that

Comment: That’s not using the array. That’s using an uninitialized pointer. Use `words` array where you actually want to get the data.

Comment: ` scanf("%[^\n]%*c", words[i]); ` This still gives Exception thrown at 0x7ABA98F1 (ucrtbased.dll) in wordgrid.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &p)`-> `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p);`

Comment: ... but wait: `char* p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));` is totally pointless. You're allocating space for a single pointer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I  was using the array instead of pointer. But it says uninitilized memory so I thought of malloc. Can you check the current for of code it still gives the same error.